# Call on another sub during an If Statement

Tags: if-statement, call, block

I have an if statement that calls on another sub once the criteria is met 
**'if isempty = true Then Call Sub FTE_Consolidation'**

All of that works fine... however, once the FTE_Consolidation sub ends, the macro continues back to the first sub and continues the series of if statements.  I don't want the macro to re-visit the 'Sub Emp_BY_PayPeriod' once I've called upon the 2nd Sub.

I've tried putting an End If at the end of 'Sub FTE Consoldation'
Still gives me the **"End If Without Block If"**

```
Sub Emp_By_PayPeriod()

Dim Mws As Worksheet
Set Mws = Workbooks("Master_Load_File.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")    

 Mws.Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("L1"), Unique:=True

If IsEmpty(Range("L2")) = True Then Call FTE_Consolidation

    Mws.Range("J1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=ActiveSheet.Range("L2").Value

    Mws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks.Add.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                                  Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\jmcgoldrick\Desktop\VBA Load FIle\Consolidated Files\IncPYRep_(Enter         Name1)_Load_(Enter Pay Period).xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close


'Next Pay Period'
If IsEmpty(Range("L3")) = True Then Call FTE_Consolidation

    Mws.Range("J1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Value

    Mws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks.Add.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                                  Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\jmcgoldrick\Desktop\VBA Load FIle\Consolidated Files\IncPYRep_(Enter Name2)_Load_(Enter Pay Period).xlsx", FileFormat:=51
   ActiveWorkbook.Close


'Next Pay Period'
 If IsEmpty(Range("L4")) = True Then Call FTE_Consolidation

    Mws.Range("J1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=ActiveSheet.Range("L4").Value

    Mws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks.Add.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                                  Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                      ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\jmcgoldrick\Desktop\VBA Load FIle\Consolidated Files\IncPYRep_(Enter Name3)_Load_(Enter Pay Period).xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close

 End Sub


 Sub FTE_Consolidation()

Dim Mws As Worksheet
Set Mws = Workbooks("Master_Load_File.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Mws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Mws.Range("L1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Mws.Range("L1").CurrentRegion.ClearFormats


'Breakout Consolidation, Summary, and VP to New Workbook'

'FTE Consolidation'
 Mws.Range("I1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>FTE"
 Mws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
     Mws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
     Mws.UsedRange.Copy

 Workbooks.Add.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                           Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
               ActiveSheet.Name = "Consolidation"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\jmcgoldrick\Desktop\VBA Load FIle\Consolidated Files\FTE Consolidated     Payroll Report (Enter_Date).xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Dim FTEws As Worksheet
Set FTEws = Workbooks("FTE Consolidated Payroll Report (Enter_Date).xlsx").Worksheets("Consolidation")

Worksheets("Consolidation").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Mws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
MsgBox "Load Files Have Been Saved Successfully!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you closing your if statements? If not, once that once of the statements runs to the sub and returns, it will continue working. If it is excluding, don´t use `If ... If ... If ...`, better `If... ElseIf... ElseIf ...Else...`. If not, at least, `If... End If ... If...End If ...`

Comment: I added elsif and End If (to close the statements) and I no longer receieve the block if erorr, however it still goes back to original sub runs the rest of the script (the other if statement(s)).  I want it to end all of my If scenarios or I'll end up looping back and forth between sub FTE Consolidation and original sub.  Notice I have 3 If statements.  If the 2nd if statement calls on Sub FTE Consolidation... it will still go back to original Sub and finish running the 3rd if statement.

Comment: So your conditions are `If Cond1 Then Do1`, `If Cond2 Then Do2` and `If Cond3 Then Do3`. If it is the case End If is missing. If not, then elseIf if not explain your algorithm idea

Comment: If cond1 then do this, if not cond1 then call on sub FTE. If cond2 then do this, if not then call on sub FTE..... etc.  the problem lies in the fact that if sub FTE is called on at any point, it will run through the code and then go back to if cond3 then do this, if not cond3 then call sub FTE.